# Android get GTALK notification data

Tags: android

I am creating an App that gives sound notification to user when he gets msg from gtalk.
Thought there is no direct access to gtalk,
is there any way to get the latest notification title and data from notification status bar?

Answer (score 0):

You would probably have to dig into [GTalk API](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/talk/talk_developers_home.html).